# Navigate between selected symbol occurrences in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I double click any symbol, it will be selected and marked with violet color (by default) in editor. Also it will give violet markers on scroll bar.

Is it possible to navigate between these occurrences with keyboard, similarly I can navigate with `F2` between error cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to navigate forth and back same as with regular search occurences.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this: [BrowseWordAtCaret Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/201?pr=idea).

Otherwise, if you are navigating over the declaration of a variable, you can use `alt-f7` (find usages).

Good luck!